# Has the Patent been abandoned? Can Someone else pick it up after being abandoned?

Tags: us3165887

In reference to the patent: [US3165887](https://www.google.com/patents/US3165887)

Answer (score 1):

This patent was granted in January 19th of 1965 and would have expired 17 years later. There is no way at this time to resurrect it. It is now free for anyone to use.

Comment: + It's generally not possible to revive someone else's patent / "pick it up".

Comment: @DonQuiKong  Especially when the patent is 52 years old.